# Testing services using spec flow

Tags: specflow

I want to test a service interface using spec flow.

The service  is designed to run tests in order to test other services. What I wanted to do is send a few request messages and get a response back and validate.

Lets say I have this Data I want to test out using the service contracts below. .

```cs
var testData = new TestData
        { Definition = new TestDefinition
            {
            Steps = new List<TestStep>(){ new TestStep{StepId = "1",  Actions = new List<TestAction>()
                                            {new TestAction{ActionType = TestActionType.SendRequest, Parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>(){{"MessageId", "1"}}},
                                            }
                                    } ,
                                new TestStep{StepId="2",Actions=new List<TestAction>
                                            {new TestAction
                                                     {ActionType=TestActionType.GetResponse,
                                                        Parameters=new Dictionary<string, string>()
                                                            {{"MessageId","2"},{"Wait","30000"}} }}}}
            },
            Requests = new List<Request>()
                {new Request(){
                            MessageId = "1", 
                            Content = new List<Element>()
                                { new Element{Key= "TransactionID.Value", Value = "XX0001"},}}},
           Response = new List<Response>{new Response
                        {MessageId="2", ElementValidations = new List<ValidationRule>
                                {new ValidationRule
                                        {Element=new Element{ Key = "TransactionID.Value",,
                                                     Value="XXX0006"},Description="Failed to match [Transaction ID] value",}}}
```

Here are the DataContracts:

```cs
[DataContract]
public class TestData
{
    [DataMember]
    public TestDefinition Definition { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public List<Request> Requests  { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public List<ExpectedResponse> Response { get; set; }

}

[DataContract]
public class TestDefinition
{
    [DataMember]
    public string TestId { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public List<TestStep> Steps { get; set; }

}

[DataContract]
public class Request
{
    [DataMember]
    public string TransactionId { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string TransactionType { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public List<Element> Content { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class TestStep
{
    public TestStep()
    {
        Timeout = 60000;
    }
    [DataMember]
    public ICollection<TestAction> Actions { get; set; }

}
```

Using spec flow using specific keywords: Scenario, Given, When, and Then. What Can I set as a Scenario, Given, When, and Then.

Here is what I am thinking to do:

1. Before scenario  [Db set up]
2. Given ["Id is found on (.*) table"]
3. When  [Prepare data to send in a table] Ex. The request data above
4. Then[validate the incoming response by looping]

Can some one help me design a good way to approach  this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For a definition of the `Given` `When` and `Then`s I'd suggest you start by reading through http://dannorth.net/introducing-bdd

In general,

**Given**

Given is the things that you can guarantee. In reality this often means that `Given`s are where you create instances and inject values to get things into the correct state. If you are using mocking, this is definitely created here too.

**When**

These are the steps that make your test perform the actions that move you from the state that you were `Given` over to the state that you expect to be in with a successful test.

**Then**

This is when you check that the code has met your expectations.

And finally,

**Scenario**

This is where we build up our `Given`s, `When`s and `Then`s into a cohesive test.

*And now for your example*

Sorry if this is unclear, but I don't think I have enough detail to really appreciate how you want this design to work.

`1.Before scenario [Db set up]`
You suggest that in your `BeforeScenario` you might setup your database. Well that's one way. Personally I would not use a database inside a test framework, I'm pretty sure that MS/Oracle etc, don't need us to test that the db stores and retrieves data, and you will find that you have problems with multiple tests running in parallel, tests execution order and being able to reset it back to a known state. Mock it instead.

On this note, you are also defining WCF contracts here, and once again we can trust WCF to get us a proxy and use a channel to communicate with the other end. So during most of your testing you don't have to set up all of that complex architecture, but instead just call a instance of the objects directly. Even if we are using SpecFlow we can still create different levels of test, from single unit tests (just one class, and often done in parallel via nUnit/MSTest), up through collaborations of classes (which is the most common feature after all), all the way to a final integration level shakedown. Just don't expect the integration level tests to pass every time if you are creating a whole WCF stack (as you end up with port overlaps etc.).

`2.Given ["Id is found on (.*) table"]` At this point we shouldn't be testing anything. You should be putting the system into the state so it is ready to start the test. Since you haven't defined anything about the database, its also a really poor implementation detail to add to your scenarios.
Instead I would suggest that this is the point when the server should be put into the state described in your first code block in the question above. You might say `Given the standard starting state` or something that is more meaningful e.g. `Given that we can handle XX0001 requests`, but inside the `[Binding]` then you will be setting this up.

`3.When [Prepare data to send in a table] Ex. The request data above`
Probably not. Again you haven't defined your Contract that has the method to execute the test (although you have alluded to it with `validate the incoming response by looping`). If you have an asynchronous design, (i.e. send the `TestDefinition` to be tested, check a flag to see if the test has finished, and when it has then pull back the result), then the `When` is everything from sending the data in until you have a result, i.e. if you have to loop (there are better ways), do it here too.

`4.Then[validate the incoming response by looping]`
Yes (apart from the looping).  Here we have a result and can now verify all of its attributes/properties to make sure that it is what we expected.

*If this is your first SpecFlow test suite*, I would recommend that you start a little more simply. Pick up just one aspect of the whole process and define your scenarios for that. Build up towards the more complicated example as you get more competent with it.

Don't forget that BDD is a process that helps you to discover the design and architecture that fits your needs exactly. You might find that what you don't need quite such an abstract framework that can handle every case just yet, but at least when you do make the switch over, then you still have all the tests to prove that the new framework works for the existing code as well.

Good luck.